# Appropriate use of "littlest"

Tags: word-usage, superlative-degree

I recently had a debate with a friend about whether "littlest" was a word.  I took the stance that it was not.  I find now that basically every time I make such a claim these days someone can hold up a phone with some web dictionary "proving me wrong".

My question is: When is it appropriate to use this word as opposed to *smallest* or some similar option?

Comment: Surely this is the least of your concerns. :)

Comment: Yes, it is an adjective synonymous with 'smallest' - there is no right or wrong time to use one vs. the other. Go with whatever sounds best to you in the context.

Comment: 'Synonymous' is often a highly questionable descriptor. See at http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23633

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Littlest* is not 'standard', but perfectly acceptable in conversation. What you should be concerned about is that it has overtones of cuteness and childish language - consider *The Littlest Mermaid*, or Google the word and see the contexts in which it is used.

I think you will usually want to avoid it. However, the same can be said of its 'standard' alternative, *least*, which is strongly marked for formality. Except in fixed phrases like *the least of your concerns* or *I haven't the least idea*, where *least* is **obligatory**, practically nobody uses *least* colloquially to mean the superlative of *little* (or *less* for its comparative).

*Smallest* is safest. *Smallest* will never make you sound like either a kindergarten teacher or a college English professor emeritus.

Comment: Even there, you have to be careful. _I haven't the smallest idea_ is not a permissible alternative to the fixed phrase you mention - in fact, _smallest_ seems to be used preferentially only when speaking about physical size.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good point; I too casually assumed that 'fixed' would be understood to imply 'obligatory'. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use *littlest* when you're talking about Lilliputians (Jonathan Swift's creations in *Gulliver's Travels*), and the "Little People" (leprechauns) of Irish folklore, and small-minded bluenoses (American Puritans) with with hearts and worldviews as big as the pea that disturbed the fairy-tale princess's sleep.

*Little* has negative connotations that make it worth using to cut someone down: "You are a little man despite your Gargantuan stature. The littlest man I've ever had the misfortune to meet, in fact."

You can also use it if you're my friend from Texas, who keeps telling me about all the "little tiny towns" he's been to in his home state. One of those towns is surely the "littlest tiny town in Texas". And since you're from Texas too, you probably know which towns he's talking about.

Comment: At least one figure respected by many has used ["little"](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+10%3A13-15&version=KJV) with no pejorative connotation.

Comment: He spoke in English on this occasion?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use *littlest* of the wee folk; though it's never occurred to me to have a superlative for them.

Comment: @Jon: Which of the three types of literary wee folk (_little people_, for those of us who don't regularly use the Scots adjective _wee_), leprechauns, hobbits, & Lilliputians is the littlest? See also: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Littlest_Hobo) about a dog on Canadian TV, & the [Shirley Temple movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Littlest_Rebel), & a [1955 movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Littlest_Outlaw).

Comment: I might use it of hobbits, I suppose.

Comment: @Edwin: What? Are you implying that Jesus wasn't American (we know that Nelson Mandela was a famous African American born & raised in South Africa) but some dadgummit furriner who jawed in a furrin tongue? And that the _Holy Bible_ wasn't printed in English about 2000 years ago? Millions of Americans will expire from shock if they read this.

Comment: Here's another example of "littlest": [The Littlest Schoolhouse](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2010/07/the-littlest-schoolhouse/308132/), an _Atlantic_ magazine article.

Comment: @Bill: That's _of Nazareth_, not _the Navajo_. On a serious note, _little_ is remarkable in that it can connote quaintness  (_a lovely little cottage_),  cuteness proper (as Stoney says) (_Lt Gruber's little tank_) or be a put-down, as you say (a tin-pot little dictator).

Comment: Can't believe [The Littlest Hobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Littlest_Hobo) has been overlooked.

Comment: For the record, Hobbits® (Tolkien) are just under 1 m tall, and Leprechauns (General Mills) are similar. Lilliputians (Swift) and Kabouter (Poortvliet) are closer to 0.15 m, with Borrowers (Norton) even shorter than that (0.12 m).

Answer (score 0):

"Littlest" is one of those words that was not a proper word when I went to grammar school in the late 1950s. It was considered incorrect to use it, and "smallest" was the correct option. Of course, that was also a time when the 't' in the word "often" was silent and not pronounced, and the pronouns " who" and " whom" we're not used interchangeably as they are today.

Comment: My guess is that it was not taught as a "proper word" in *your grammar school*. It was not generally thought of as improper in the 1950s, AFAIK.