# Superlative form of the adjective "little" for degree or intensity

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree, suppletion

[Inflections of 'little' (adj)](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/little):

> 1. For **size or age**:
>
> **Littler** ("That tree is little, but the tree next
> to it is even littler."). **Littlest** ("Theo is the littlest of my three
> little brothers.")
>
> 2. For **amount**:
>
> **less** (e.g. "I have little money. Certainly less money
> than him.") **Least** (—e.g. "I have little money, but Jim is the one who
> has least money out of all of us.")
>
> 3. For **degree or intensity**
>
> **Lesser** (—e.g. "She has little love for him.
> Certainly, her love for him is lesser than her love for her mother.")

Then what's the superlative form of the adjective "*little*" for degree or intensity?

Comment: I doubt that there is one. Even for size, _smaller_ and _smallest_ would be more commonly used.

Comment: @KateBunting **LESSER** [comparative of little with least as superlative.]
1) adj. 
smaller, as in size, value, or importance: _a lesser evil._ 2) 

adv.
**less**.  https://www.wordreference.com/definition/LESS

Comment: 'Certainly, her love for him is lesser than her love for her mother' is antiquated (at best), unidiomatic. _less_. 'But her love for cousin Ignatius was least.'

Comment: @KateBunting 'Littlest' certainly exists in idiomatic speech. It is sufficiently familiar that there is a sentimental children's film and several TV series called [The Littlest Hobo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121943/) with a dog hero who is a cross between Lassie and Kwai Chang Caine from the 1970s Kung Fu series.

Comment: @BoldBen I didn't say that _littlest_ didn't exist, but I associate it mainly with, as you say, sentimental references to small children or animals.

Comment: @KateBunting I'd say that that was true to a greater or lesser extent for the word 'little' in all its forms. It always seems to have that association to me. I get the impression that 'small' was gradually inserted between 'little' and 'petty' in the 17th, 18th and 19th centuries displacing them both. I know that it existed before that but documents from before that time seem to use it less than 'little' and 'petty' and, even then, in the sense of 'slim' or 'narrow'.There is a folk song which has the phrase "his fingers being both long and small" which sounds almost impossible to modern ears.

Comment: I have heard teachers in India use little, less/lesser, least for positive, comparative and superlative degrees.  Ref.https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-quantifiers-graded.htm;  I know these may not suit the OP's question, though.

Comment: a lesser/greater quantity or amount: the least, the most. BUT NOT: lesser love in terms of having it. The word love is not the best example as it may give itself to being described in terms of intensity it does not in terms of amount. You end up **having to say** a greater amount of love, which sounds horrible (Chicago accent).

Comment: It's already been stated on English Language Learners that it's little - lesser - least. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/820/is-it-less-than-or-lesser-than You can also check Random House here https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lesser

Answer (score 1):

"Littlest"

There is a [thread about it here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104271/appropriate-use-of-littlest).  Seems like it's a bit debatable whether is 100% correct but while it sounds kind of funny I think it's perfectly fine.  However you can usually find a better way to more accurately describe what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The superlative corresponding to “lesser” is “(the) least”, as in “to the least extent” vs. “to a lesser extent”.

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00132089 AND https://oed.com/oed2/00131088